# Get Failed Coupon/Gift Card In Checkout UI Extension

Tags: shopify

const applyDiscountCodeChange = useApplyDiscountCodeChange();
const applyGiftCardChange = useApplyGiftCardChange();

const listAppliedDiscountList = useDiscountCodes();
const listAppliedGiftCards = useAppliedGiftCards();

By using these hooks I can apply or remove coupons/gift cards and also able to get the list of applied gift cards(But this happens only for custom text box and custom button not with default text and button).

I requirement is that when ever user types anything in the Shopify default text of reduce(gift/copuon card) and clicks on apply then in the error condition I want to get the failed code because I want to call an API there.

const applyDiscountCodeChange = useApplyDiscountCodeChange();
const applyGiftCardChange = useApplyGiftCardChange();

const listAppliedDiscountList = useDiscountCodes();
const listAppliedGiftCards = useAppliedGiftCards();

By using these hooks I can apply or remove coupons/gift cards and also able to get the list of applied gift cards(But this happens only for custom text box and custom button not with default text and button).